# Custom request with i18next-http-backend

Tags: i18next, i18next-http-backend

I am likely missing some simple solution, but I would like to know how one would send a custom request using `i18next-http-backend` with a url that cannot be defined by the `loadPath` option. I had though it would be easily done via the `request` function, but the issue there is that the namespaces and locales being requested are not part of the arguments list. As a result the only option I had come up with is JSON encoding them in a `loadPath` function to then decode them in the `request` function, but that feels unnecessarily convoluted.